# insert vs emplace when dealing with rvalues

Tags: c++, stl, std

```cpp
std::string myString;
std::unordered_set<std::string> mySet;

mySet.insert(std::move(myString));
mySet.emplace(std::move(myString)); // this is an example, in reality you can't move twice
```

I understand the difference between `insert` and `emplace`. But is there any practical difference when doing it with `std::move`? Which one is preferrable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differences are few or none, depending on the container type.

The container you chose, `std::unordered_set`, can **fail to insert/emplace** if an equal element already exists in the container.

In this failure case, `emplace` may perform unnessesary additional steps of allocating a node and constructing the object there (to perform a hash), then destructing the object and deallocating the node.

Prefer `insert` when you know the type you are passing is the contained type

Comment: Interesting! I wonder if `.emplace()` is allowed to perform this optimization too.

Comment: Honored to catch the interst of @HolyBlackCat ... cppreference uses the word "may" for this scenario

Comment: I've asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77245250/2752075), hopefully not a dupe...