# Is `[unordered_]set::emplace()` allowed to not construct a temporary element if it already exists in the set?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77245073/2752075) points out something interesting:

A naively implemented `std::unordered_set<T>::emplace()` is slower than `insert()` when given an object of type `T` that already exists in the container, because `insert()` can detect that and exit immediately, but a naive `emplace()` would allocate a node first, construct the element, then check for uniqueness, and destroy&deallocate it if it already exists.

That's certainly the case when `emplace` is given `!= 1` argument, because it can't make sense of them without calling the constructor. But perhaps the case of 1 argument can be optimized.

Presumably all that applies to `std::set<T>::emplace()` as well. So, two questions:

1. Does the standard allow `emplace()` to not construct an object in that case? I.e. if only one argument is passed, and `remove_cvref_t<argument-type>` matches the element type, can `emplace()` apply `==`/`<`/hash the argument directly, without constructing a new object?

   - And what about transparent comparators? If the argument of `emplace` is comparable with the element type, can it be compared directly, without constructing a full element?
2. Do contemporary implementations actually do this optimization in practice?

Comment: Stumbled upon a few similar questions, but found no conclusive answers at the first glance.

Comment: Depending on the comparator, a `std::set` could also use this optimization on a parameter that is not the same type, but is a comparable type.

Comment: As far as I understand, there is no requirement put on that by standard: http://www.eel.is/c++draft/associative.reqmts#general-49 (compare it to requirement "there is no effect" for [std::map::try_emplace](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/map.modifiers#4)). So this would be within "as-if" rule territory.

Comment: @DrewDormann Right, and we now have transparent hashing too, so `unordered_set` could also attempt that... Added it into the question.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen So by default it looks like it can't optimize anything, unless there's a requirement somewhere that copying/moving an element requires `==`/`<`/hashing the new one to give the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the standard allow emplace() to not construct an object in that case?

No, [[associative.reqmts]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/associative.reqmts#tab:container.assoc.req) and [[unord.req]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/unord.req#tab:container.hash.req) (for `std::set` and `std::unordered_set` respectively) require only that the arguments to `emplace` are *Cpp17EmplaceConstructible* into the container and there is no additional semantic requirement. `emplace` is also specified to compare with the key of the object that would be inserted into the container.

As specified in [[container.requriments.general]/16.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/containers#container.requirements.general-16.5) *Cpp17EmplaceConstructible* only requires the validity of the `std::allocator_traits::construct` expression that the allocator-aware container needs to use to construct the object into the container per [[container.requirements.general]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/containers#container.requirements.general-3).

For the standard allocator `std::allocator`, `construct` will simply use the corresponding direct-initialization from the argument list to construct the object. This generally does not impose any requirement on how the value of the constructed object relates to the original object. It doesn't even need to result in a call to a copy or move constructor. For other allocators, `construct` is only required to construct an object of the intended type, without any semantic requirements (see [[allocator.requirements.general]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/library#allocator.requirements.general-2)).

So, there is no requirement that the key of the element that would be inserted will be equivalent to the key of the passed object and therefore the optimization is generally not valid. (But the as-if rule does of course still apply.)

For `insert` the specification requires *Cpp17CopyInsertable* or *Cpp17MoveInsertable* instead. These specifically enforce that the object that would be constructed in the container is equivalent to the passed object per [[container.requirements.general]/16.3 and 16.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/container.requirements.general#16.3) and the specification of `insert` also requires comparison with the passed object's key instead of the one that would be constructed in the container.

Answer (score 2):

> Do contemporary implementations actually do this optimization in practice?

This part of the question can be answered experimentally. Consider the following program:

```cpp
#include <set>

struct A {
    A(int){}
    // any attempt of calling copy constructor will result in exception and program termination
    A(const A&) { throw 1; }
    // all objects of A are identical, so operator < always returns false
    bool operator <(const A&) const { return false; }
};

int main() {
    std::set<A> s;
    // successfully creates the first element in the set
    s.emplace(1);
    // unsuccessfully tries to add the same element, and throws if temporary element is created
    s.emplace(A(1));
}
```

This program indeed fails with `terminate called after throwing...` in `libstdc++`, but succeeds in `libc++` and MS STL:
https://godbolt.org/z/hTMzMhrfx

(Please note that commenting the first `s.emplace(1);` will result to program fail in all implementations).

In MS STL the execution comes to

```
template <class _Key>
struct _In_place_key_extract_set<_Key, _Key> {
    // we can extract the key in emplace if the emplaced type is identical to the key type
    static constexpr bool _Extractable = true;
    static const _Key& _Extract(const _Key& _Val) noexcept {
        return _Val;
    }
};
```

and the comment proves to us that such optimization exists in reality.

Comment: Interesting. I do not see how this is justified by the standard though. This doesn't consider the possibility of a different allocator that uses completely different semantics in `construct` either.

Comment: In [LWG issue 2177](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2177) Howard Hinnant states that he believes the requirements on _*Insertable_ are already implied without the explicit text that was added, but unfortunately the linked discussions aren't public and so I don't know on what he is basing this. I also think that it is weird _EmplaceConstructible_ didn't get extra verbiage as well, if the discrepancy wasn't intentionally.